# calculation of determinant: why a(a b c d) will be a^{2}?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I've just started to study linear algebra, and this is my 1st post to this site.

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYWIc.jpg)

I understand that if $\mathbf {X=[a\quad b\quad c\quad d]}$ then the determinant will be $\mathbf {aX+b X+c X+d X}+1$.
But I don't understand why it'll become $\mathbf {aX+b X+c X+d X}+1 =||\mathbf a||^{2}+||\mathbf b||^{2}+||\mathbf c||^{2}+||\mathbf d||^{2}+1$

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You've only posted the answer. Try posting the original *problem*. What is given? What is being asked here? And are $a,b,c,d$ vectors or single numbers? If they're column vectors (so that $X$ is square), then $aX$ is undefined.

Comment: @Carl, I'm Sorry for my question being difficult to understand. The original problem is on the pic I posted with my question. You'll see some Japanese words after $a^2b^2-a^2c^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+1$, that means "Show (imperative form)." I mean this is a proof question.

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate $$\left|\begin{matrix}a^2+1&ab&ac&ad\\ba&b^2+1&bc&bd\\ca&cb&c^2+1&cd\\da&db&dc&d^2+1\end{matrix}\right|$$

Perhaps looking at smaller, similar determinants helps.  For $n=2$ we want to show
$$\left|\begin{matrix}a^2+1&ab\\ba&b^2+1\end{matrix}\right|=a^2+b^2+1$$
On the left we have $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)-a^2b^2$ so the answer is immediate.

For $n=3$
$$\left|\begin{matrix}a^2+1&ab&ac\\ba&b^2+1&bc\\ca&cb&c^2+1\end{matrix}\right|=\\(a^2+1)(b^2+c^2+1)-ab\left|\begin{matrix}ba&bc\\ca&c^2+1\end{matrix}\right|+ac\left|\begin{matrix}ba&b^2+1\\ca&cb\end{matrix}\right|=\\(a^2+1)(b^2+c^2+1)-a^2b^2\left|\begin{matrix}1&c\\c&c^2+1\end{matrix}\right|+a^2c^2\left|\begin{matrix}b&b^2+1\\1&b\end{matrix}\right|=\\
(a^2+1)(b^2+c^2+1)-a^2b^2-a^2c^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+1$$
as desired.

Similarly groady calculations will presumably give $n=4$.  I am unable to find a shorter path, sad to say.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! With your help, I could review what I studied of how to calculate determinants.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v=\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{pmatrix}$, 
$e_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, 
$e_2=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$, 
$e_3=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$, and
$e_4=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Then
\begin{align*}
&\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
a^2+1&ab&ac&ad\\
ba&b^2+1&bc&bd\\
ca&cb&c^2+1&cd\\
da&db+1&dc&d^2+1
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&\qquad=
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
av+e_1&
bv+e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\[10pt]
&\qquad=
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
av&
bv+e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
bv+e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\[10pt]
&\qquad=
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
av&
bv+e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
bv&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&\qquad\quad+
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\[10pt]
&\qquad=
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
av&
bv+e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
bv&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&\qquad\quad+
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
cv&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\[10pt]
&\qquad=
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
av&
bv+e_2&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
bv&
cv+e_3&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&\qquad\quad+
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
cv&
dv+e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
e_3&
dv
\end{matrix}
\right\vert
+
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
e_3&
e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\[10pt]
&\qquad=x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+1,
\end{align*}
where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ represent the first four determinants,
respectively. Now, if $a=0$, then $x_1=0=a^2$ trivially, and if $a\neq 0$,
\begin{align*}
x_1&=
a\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
v&
e_2&
e_3&
e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&=
a\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
ae_1+be_2+ce_3+de_4&
e_2&
e_3&
e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&=a^2
\left\vert
\begin{matrix}
e_1&
e_2&
e_3&
e_4
\end{matrix}
\right\vert\\
&=a^2.
\end{align*}
So combine the two cases, we have $x_1=a^2$. Use the same argument to discuss $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$,
we also have $x_2=b^2$, $x_3=c^2$, and $x_4=d^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now I understand the solution quite clearly.